# What is the sorting order precedence of the AngularJS `orderBy` filter?

Tags: angularjs

What is the sorting order precedence in AngularJS if we use orderBy?
eg: ["a1","_a1","A1","1"]

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

> In short, it compares numbers numerically, strings alphabetically
>   (and case-insensitively), for objects falls back to using their index
>   in the original collection, sorts values of different types by type
>   and puts undefined and null values at the end of the sorted list.

Working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.data = ["a1", "_a1", "A1", "1"];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <p ng-repeat="data in vm.data |orderBy" ng-bind="data"></p>
</div>
```